# Looking to figure out a way to scroll a lot of content while keeping the header and sidebar visible on Google Sites

Tags: html, google-sites

I created my website on Google sites and there appears to be no way to have the header and sidebar in a fixed position. I have a lot of content on each page that people need to scroll through, so what I'd ideally like to do is figure out some html code for the content area where I can have all the content scroll and not the page itself so you can always see the header and sidebar.

I was able to find html for a scrollbar but it appears that when you're scrolling through it, the main page starts moving and doing a whole bunch of wonky things.

Is there any simple coding that I could put in where it's just very easy to scroll through the content without having the header and sidebar move?

I am very, very new to coding and there's a possibility my question doesn't even make sense. Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the 
     `position:fixed;`

Hope this helps
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dMLX7/280/)